# Msbuild and VStudio generate different project.assets.json files

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, csproj

This question is about the differences in the content of the NET 5 project.assets.json file when Visual Studio or Msbuild generate the file. My experiments have shown the following findings:

- VStudio regenerates the project.assets.json file on each ‘clean’ operation.
- VStudio creates only a target `net5.0-windows7.0` in the json
  file.
- VStudio can build and debug the project within only
  `net5.0-windows7.0` in the json file.
- VStudio does not create a target `net5.0-windows7.0/win-x64` in
  the json file.
- Msbuild requires a target `net5.0-windows7.0/win-x64` for a
  successful build.
- MsBuild will not regenerate the project.assets.json file if it
  exists.
- Msbuild fails on a VS-generated project.assets.json file.

The only way I can get a successful build with msbuild is to delete the obj/project.assets.json file and let msbuild regenerate it (probably with a restore operation). When msbuild regenerates the json file, it includes BOTH targets for `net5.0-windows7.0` and `net5.0-windows7.0/win-x64`.

I have experimented with various combinations and permutations of Platform=x64/AnyCPU, PlatformTarget=x64/AnyCPU, and RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64 in the csproj file, but without success. The only way I can get a successful msbuild on the command line is to delete all existing project.asset.json files for all projects involved in the build.

Here is my msbuild command line:

```
msbuild  /t:clean;restore;publish /p:Platform=AnyCPU /p:PlatformTarget=AnyCPU /p:Configuration=Debug /p:TargetFramework=net5.0-windows7.0  /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64 /p:SelfContained=false /p:PublishProtcol=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=true MyFile.csproj
```

Here is my csproj file (I added RuntimeIdentifer=win-x64 and Platforms/Target=AnyCPU;x64 in the permutations, but they did not help.)

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU</Platforms>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows7.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Here is the Project.assets.json file generated by VStudio:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "targets": {
    "net5.0-windows7.0": {}
  },
. . . no runtimes section in the VStudio-generated file
```

Here is the Project.assets.json generated by MsBuild:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "targets": {
    "net5.0-windows7.0": {},
    "net5.0-windows7.0/win-x64": {}
  },
. . . 
  "runtimes": {
      "win-x64": {
        "#import": []
      }
    }
```

Q. Is this normal behavior for VS and msbuild?

Q. Why doesn’t `msbuild /t:clean;restore;publish` automatically regenerate the file using the arguments on the msbuild command line? If VS can automatically regenerate the file on a `clean` operation, why won’t msbuild do the same thing?

Q. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a way to avoid deleting the project.asset.json files before every msbuild operation?

Comment: I'm running into the same thing with .NET 7 for a C++/CLI project. I can build it from the VS 2022 GUI but I can't build it from our build system because nothing is creating the C++/CLI project's `obj\project.assets.json` file.  I've tried `nuget restore`, `dotnet restore` and `msbuild foo.sln -t:restore`. None of those work.  This is driving me batty.

Comment: I set <EnableManagedPackageReferenceSupport> to false in the .vcxproj file and that got rid of the problem for me. The project no longer generates a project.assets.json file.

Comment: Oh, that sounds promising! I will try it the next time I work on that project. THANK YOU for posing an answer - I gave up long ago.

Comment: To be clear, I ran into this with a C++/CLI project. I'm not sure if that setting is valid in a C# .csproj file.